# Does anyone know how to use the Ubercart UC VAT module?

Tags: ubercart

I have to implement different VAT for different products (regardless of the category). Some products can have 19%, some 4%, some 6%, and some they don't have a VAT rate at all.

So far I couldn't even specify a global 19% vat.

I don't understand how this is handled. I've searched for documentation but it's almost nonexistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAT module adds 'VAT settings' tab to your Store administration > Configuration > Tax Rates and Settings (/admin/store/settings/taxes), where you can specify global VAT value.

Comment: yes meanwhile I've figured that out, just remains some details about conditions and stuff, it seems that the conditions and actions are failing sometimes, I'm getting some foreach errors when applying some taxes for some class types only

Comment: @PartySoft Good luck with that. Sounds like a bit of a headache.